# How to handle PUT and DELETE HTTP request in a PHP API First App?

Tags: php, api, rest

I am wanting to build an API first RESTful application in PHP.  I have never attempted to do this so I have some questions about how to handle `PUT` and `DELETE`

So for an example if I have a API endpoint that updates a User profile, should I make it accept BOTH a `POST` and `PUT` Request?

If I was building a Client for my API as a Desktop app or iOS app, etc it would be easy to send a `PUT` request to my API but I plan to have a Web based app for my API as well.

So on my web based app, I would have an HTML Form to Update a User profile, this would then be sent as a `POST` as HTML Forms do not allow `PUT` requests.

Could someone with more experience with this explain the best way to handle my example scenario?

Would the proper way be to send my Form as a `POST` to my PHP script, then my PHP script would make a proper `PUT` request to my PHP API with cURL?

Comment: (not a full answer, so using comment) Well, your form would be on your website, so it would be posting to your website, not your RESTful API, so separate the distinction there, and the problem should simplify.

Comment: @Uberfuzzy I understand what you are saying however this isn't going to be like an Add-on API, I am talking about an API First site.  Where you build an API then build the site to USE the API as any other client would use it

Comment: If your'e in need of a framework to start of with https://github.com/victorjonsson/PHP-Rocker

Answer (score 2):

You can absolutely also do PUT requests from browsers, but you need javascript.

Generally I would say a good way to think about it, is as follows:

First build a great REST api that follows all the rules. Only once you are at that point, think about the workarounds you need to make it work in other contexts. Submitting an HTML form is a valid thing to need a workaround for.

However, since 'POST' is completely open for interpretation, and has little rules associated, one option would be to create a single resource (or url) on your server that handles all the POST requests coming from browsers. (something like `/browserpost`).

You could always add a hidden `<input>` field with `name="url"` that specifies which resource was actually intended to be updated, and an `<input>` with `name="method" value="PUT"` for the intention.

You will need to add CSRF protection anyway, so I feel this would be a solid way to deal with this this. 1 endpoint to specifically 'proxy' html-based form submissions and internally do the appropriate mappings to the correct REST services.

Answer (score 0):

I would use `GET` `POST` `PUT` `DELETE` as they are described in HTTP. That's restful (in my opinion). As regular browser forms does not support this I would send the data via AJAX.

If you really need to use browser forms,  maybe because javascript is not enabled, then using `POST` requests with a param like `?method` sounds like a suitable solution - although I don't like it.